# Groovy, overloading << operator on ZipOutputStream

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading

based on Google I managed to write a little Groovy script that packs a zip just as I needed.

```
ZipOutputStream zipOutput = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("${uid}.pufi"));

ZipEntry mainentry = new ZipEntry('main.xml')
zipOutput.putNextEntry(mainentry)
zipOutput << "mainmainmain"
zipOutput.closeEntry()

ZipEntry manifentry = new ZipEntry('manifest.xml')
zipOutput.putNextEntry(manifentry)
zipOutput << new FileInputStream(options.manifest)
zipOutput.closeEntry()
```

It works, but I would like to know how does Groovy figure out what to call on lines `entry << "foobar"` or `entry << new FileInputStream(..)`. As I see ZipOutputStream is a Java class, its javadoc doesn't contain any method, that could be called with even String or InputStream arguments. Could you explain me how does it work and where is it documented? I'd like to know more about Groovy.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy adds additional methods to some basic Java classes in order to use them in a more *groovy* way. For a complete overview af the additional methods look at http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk. In your case, the method `leftShift` was added the class [OutputStream](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/OutputStream.html). Groovy also overloads the `<<` operator, so it's the same as calling the method `leftShift` on the object.